# Transferring selected values as parameters from embedded GoodData dashboards

Tags: parameters, hyperlink, analytics, dashboard, gooddata

Is there any supported method in transferring selected values as parameters from embedded GoodData dashboards to embedding target systems? Prospect is concerning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuya,

Thank you for your question. It depends what kind of values you mean. You can definitely use Dashboard macros to extract selected values from the GoodData and use them. For example Project ID, Filter value etc. See the article:

https://developer.gooddata.com/article/dashboard-macro-reference

Or you can use iframe events to handle different situations like :

https://developer.gooddata.com/article/embedded-dashboard-events

I hope this helps you. Feel free to ask more if needed!

JT

Comment: Hi Jiri,Thank you for your clarification. Additionally, I would like to know whether there is any way in dashboard macros to pass not only filtering conditions but filtered results like the general business attribute values (matched category values) from the embedded dashboard into the external frame web application.

Comment: I mean that I have an expectation to dashboard macro functionality also to pass searched results like displayed attribute values.

Comment: I knew that GoodData API like /gdc/exporter/executor ( http://developer.gooddata.com/api#report ) can export filtered values which I am arguing in JSON from embedded inline GoodData dashboard frame to parent web application frame. I would like to know how and where I can declare such GoodData report value export API and how and by what sort of event such API call can be called from or passed to the parent web application frame.

Comment: Hey Yuya, can you send me an email with your use case? I don't understand 100% of your question and it would be helpful ;)